# Plase explain me the statment related to interior point in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

[image]

I wrote such definition at the class. I understand the definition. But also my teacher said " needs provoing!"  I underlined it with blue pencil. I could not understand what my teacher wants us and why he wrote such proof requirment. Please explain me. How do I prove this? Ans ıs this important?

Comment: How do you define $E^\circ$?

Comment: You probably missed writing "$E°$ *is open*". That's what you need to prove, I think.

Comment: I definied as the union of the set {$V :$ $V \subseq E$ and $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$} @copper.hat

Comment: Hmm okay Maybe.. @GiuseppeNegro

Comment: Can you see from that definition that the set of interior points must be in $E^\circ$? So you just need to show that if $x \in E^\circ$ then it must be an interior point. But if $x\in E^\circ$, then $x \in V$ for some open set contained in $E$, hence...

Comment: Yes, I see. If $x \in E^{o}$, What do I need to show that? I dont understand that part you said? Sorry @copper.hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $E^o$ is open, note that if $x \in E^o$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)  \subseteq E$.  For any $y \in B_\epsilon(x)$, let $$\delta_y = \frac{\epsilon - d(x,y)}{2}$$

Then $B_{\delta_y}(y) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}(x)$, so $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq E^o$.

Comment: $d(x,y)$ means $||x-y||$. Is this right?

Comment: @B11b Yes, in the case of Euclidean space, but the result holds in any metric space.